# Adb not running

Tags: android, sockets, debian, adb

I am running a freshly installed Debian 7.0 Wheezy 64bits. I backported adb with Debian build facilities following this tutorial http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/280-debian-wheezy-android-tools-adb-fastboot-qtadb

I have the following problem with ADB. It does start, but instead of creating a TCPIP socket it create a file socket in /tmp with the port name. I tried starting with root the adb server but same issue. Here is a shel output for example

```
hydrogen ~ # adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
hydrogen ~ # adb devices
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
** daemon still not running
error: cannot connect to daemon
hydrogen ~ # netstat -a | grep 5037
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     30187    /tmp/5037
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     28409    /tmp/5037
hydrogen ~ # lsof -la /tmp/5037 
COMMAND  PID     USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF  NODE NAME
adb     7531        0    6u  unix 0xffff8800bcb0e5c0      0t0 30187 /tmp/5037
adb     7535        0    5u  unix 0xffff8801106efc00      0t0 28409 /tmp/5037
```

Any hints where I could search for this issue ?

Comment: why won't you just use the official Google binary? http://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools_r17-linux.zip

Comment: Hi Alex, 
Thanks for the hint. It indeed works, I just had to install libncurses5:i386 to get the precompiled adb to work.

In the mean time someone also pointed me towards this official Debian bug: http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715238 which corresponds exactly to my issue. Let's hope they will fix it.

Comment: Yep, testing the patch suggested in the Debian bugreport, solve the issue with the file socket.

Answer (score 0):

Yep,

The last patch suggested in [the Debian bug report](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=715238) solve the issue.

```
hydrogen android # adb start-server
* daemon not running. starting it now on port 5037 *
* daemon started successfully *
hydrogen android # adb devices
List of devices attached 

hydrogen android # netstat -a | grep adb
hydrogen android # netstat -a | grep 5037
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     483635   /tmp/5037
```

Sorry for the noise. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a TCP socket using `socat` to redirect connections to the unix socket:

`socat TCP-LISTEN:5037,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/tmp/5037`

;)